# What is this thin copper tube for?

Tags: plumbing, water, basement, leaks

I knocked this pipe with my head while cleaning the basement and it started dripping water. Confused because it’s the only pipe down there that’s this thin, it has a weird dial on it and it seems to connect to another switch.

[image]
[image]

Does it seem like tightening the bolt will fix the drip or do I have to address all the stuff built up around it?

Comment: Could be anything.  What's above it? A toilet?   A fridge with an ice-maker?

Comment: I'd add dishwasher to the list of possibles, though for that I would expect a hot-water connection. By the way, the "dial" is a cut-off valve.

Comment: Above it is the kitchen so could be a number of things, my guess is the water line for the fridge, as the fridge is new and I bet when they installed it, they added the line (cutting into the cold water pipe there?) and did it as quickly and cheaply as possible because that's how it goes. Ugh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a common connection for an ice maker or a humidifier. You'll have to experiment to find out which. You can try tightening up the nuts on the valve. Those are compression fittings and tightening them up can usually solve the problem. Clean off the valve with some vinegar.

Comment: This sounds right. It's above the kitchen and a relatively new fridge was installed a couple years ago by previous owners who cut every corner imaginable.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it is for a fridge water line for either water or an ice maker. Or both if your fridge has them. It looks like it is in the open position. I would white it down to see where it is leaking from.  If you are comfortable with it find were it is leaking from go upstream and shut off the water and replace it. If not completely comfortable with it call a plumber before it becomes a bigger issue.

Comment: "I would white it down to see where it is leaking from." How does one "white it down"? Please [edit] for clarity.

Comment: Maybe WIPE it down?

Answer (score 3):

Look at all that blue oxidation due to moisture. That pipe has been leaky for a while.

That connection is using a compression fitting and it seems to be failing, given all that white buildup at the connection point.

To have a pipe so haphazardly hanging around like that is a sign of someone who didn't care about the install. I would definitely seek to properly fix that line.

Comment: Thanks this is all helpful. I'd love to fix this but intimidated by plumbing, I shut off the valve, buy the parts, agh. But calling a plumber seems like $500 just to get them in the door in my area. Is that what homeowners do, drop $300 or $500 on a problem like this? New homeowner here these costs are adding up!

Comment: @podcastfan88 Welcome to home ownership =). You could get two crescent wrenches and try tightening down the compression fittings like the other answer suggested; it would probably stop the leak. If you bump your head again then the leak will likely start again. That line is soft copper so it deforms easily. It should have been installed up and out of the way. 2 years after moving into my house I had to rip out all of the plumbing and install PEX. It costed about $1,100 in materials; I don't even want to think about what a plumber would have charged.

Answer (score 1):

The valve on the right is going to be a problem, the saddle valve looks like it is ready to fail. They clamp on a copper pipe and pearce it when you first rotate the handle clockwise. That puts a small hole in the tube. It turns off by sealing the hole usually with the same steel tip used to puncture the tube. That corrodes over time and will not seal. The gasket can fail and it will leak. If you repair it put in a normal "T" (I use sweat fittings) and reduce it down to the appropriate valve. Compression fittings would work also.

If you have no experience or soldering skill I would use compression fittings. You will need a tubing cutter and a few wrenches. You would need to turn the water off and bleed pressure off of the line. That can be accomplished by opening a faucet. When the water quits flowing you can close the faucet and remove the old valve and note where the pinhole is as you will need to cut a bit of the copper tubing to fit the valve, be sure the hole is in the part you cut out. Expect some water to come out when you cut it. If the water sprays out when you removed the old valve you did not turn the correct supply valve off.

Having a bucket or two will help a shop vac would be even better. Once the section of copper tubing is removed remove the compression nuts from the "T". Be sure you do not damage the ferals. you slide the nut on the copper pipe, then the feral then the "T". Do the same on the other side, you will need to be able to move the copper tube about an inch so be sure you can do that before starting. once you have the "T" in place orenate the direction you want, connect the valve and tighten the nuts, best to snug them up then use a wrench on each nut you tighten them until tight. From the valve you will need a reducing fitting to fit the tubing (probably 1/4"). Then turn the new valve off and then turn the water on slow and watch for leaks.

If you can have somebody help you that would be great. Also when you get the parts at the local box store go over what you are doing with them, they can be a big help and be sure you have the correct parts.

Some of the big box stores in my area offer courses on stuff like this over the year and normally they are free. This does not have to be done immediately take the course first. If you are not comfortable with this best to hire a plumber and watch how he does it.

Comment: Thanks for the details, this helps though it expands the scope of the problem (to the appropriate size I guess). Exhausted by these problems. How much do you think a plumber would charge for a job like this? I'm game to try, but so far when I start one job I cause another problem that triggers another job. Worried if I tackle this I will cause some other error that will lead to an even larger repair!

Comment: Welcome to the busy life of a homeowner. In about a year you will have a handle on it and be comfortable with most repairs.